# Удобное и быстрое чтение больших текстовых файлов (2-3 ТБ) на C#

Tags: c#, парсер, текст, десериализация

Мне нужно обработать достаточно большие текстовые файлы (размером до нескольких терабайт), состоящие из временн**ы**х последовательностей фреймов (блоков, записей?) следующего вида:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP                                   // заголовок
0
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS
1000
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
8.1154268336647561e-01 3.0288457316633668e+01
8.1154268336647561e-01 3.0288457316633668e+01
8.1154268336647561e-01 3.0288457316633668e+01
ITEM: ATOMS id type xs ys zs                     // основная часть
1 1 0.0458303 0.0893053 0.087739                 // координаты, скорости и т. п.
2 1 0.120217 0.00714859 0.1049
3 1 0.0827161 0.160408 0.0186651
4 1 0.140222 0.136071 0.0827429
5 1 0.222306 0.106146 0.107203
...
1000 1 0.633306 0.0643522 0.0981721
```

Каждый такой фрейм содержит заголовок и основную часть в виде столбцов с координатами, скоростями и т. п. Не все поля из заголовка нужны для обработки. Не все столбцы из основной части нужны для обработки. Данные из файла читаются по одному фрейму.

В настоящее время метод чтения файла выглядит примерно так:

```
private bool ReadTimestep(StreamReader sr)
{
    if (sr.EndOfStream) return false;

    sr.ReadLine(); // ITEM: TIMESTEP
    sr.ReadLine(); // %d
    sr.ReadLine(); // ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS

    numberOfAtoms = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

    sr.ReadLine(); // ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp
    sr.ReadLine(); // %f %f
    sr.ReadLine(); // %f %f
    sr.ReadLine(); // %f %f

    sr.ReadLine(); // ITEM: ATOMS id x y z

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfAtoms; i++)
    {
        var tokens = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        pos[i].X = float.Parse(tokens[1]);
        pos[i].Y = float.Parse(tokens[2]);
        pos[i].Z = float.Parse(tokens[3]);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Такой подход очень прост и достаточно производителен, но требует правки и перекомпиляции программы даже при небольших изменениях формата данных (например изменение количества или порядка столбцов в основной части фрейма).

Существуют ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для C#, позволяющие более элегантно организовать чтение такого файла?

Comment: Что значит "элегантно"? Если меняется формат данных - значит что то не так. У вас есть описания типов данных `ITEM: ATOMS id type xs ys zs` - по ним и ориентируйтесь.

Comment: И вообще, читать жестко заданное число строк когда есть заголовки - это не правильно. Читайте до значения пока не получите нужный заголовок, в данном случае `ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS` и `ITEM: ATOMS id type xs ys zs`

Comment: @ГеннадийП Под "элегантно" я подразумеваю способ, где не надо колхозить чтение через множество подряд идущих `StreamReader.ReadLine()`, `string.Trim()` и `string.Split()`. Что-то наподобие библиотек для чтения CSV.

Comment: Ну я подсказал: Читайте по заголовкам и опирайтесь на данные заголовков.

Comment: Код выглядит вполне элегантно (с учётом комментариев) и очень понятно. Можно, конечно, заюзать LINQ, регулярки и просто чтение с проверками типа `if (readString.StartsWith("ITEM: ATOMS"))`, но это наверняка ударит по производительности.

Comment: Если напрягает перекомпиляция, то вынесите код парсинга в отдельную маленькую библиотеку. Она будет компилиться мгновенно.

Comment: Регулярки никто не отменял. А чтобы оно было быстро, можно строки раскидывать несколько потоков с буферизацией, или хотя-бы в один, но тот который парсит данные не в потоке чтения, чтобы читать данные с максимальной скоростью. А сами регулярки - это строки, которые можно просто редактировать в интерфейсе. Таким образом можно пилить свои шаблоны для парсинга без перекомпиляции. Достаточно элегантно?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `но это наверняка ударит по производительности` "Преждевременная оптимизация – корень всех зол"

Comment: А существуют ли библиотеки для более высокоуровневого написания шаблонов парсинга чем на регулярках? Потому что даже для десятичной дроби в экспоненциальной форме получается не самая тривиальная регулярка. А для целого файла получится уж совсем write-only конструкция.

Comment: @ГеннадийП - Преждевременная пессимизация - источник не меньшего количества зол. 2-3 Тб - это много. Если сразу не подумать о производительности, то потом поздняк метаться, придётся переписывать весь код.

Comment: У файла есть структура, за заголовочной строкой идет группа других строк. Зачем писать регулярку для всего файла, если можно отталкиваться от его структуры, и регулярить построчно тем шаблоном, который ожидается в блоке. Регулярка нужна для извлечения данных из строки, не более, она как раз решит вопрос изменения формата строки. Здесь нет серебряной пули в моем предложении, а лишь вариант решения одной части вашей весьма комплексной задачи. Не стоит его натягивать на 2 терабайта данных, вы все равно не сможете прочитать их целиком в память.